# Android - JSON throwing exception

Tags: android, json, exception

So, I have a school project where I have to parse a json array and put the data in a listview. 
Here is the json http://demo4404797.mockable.io/speakers

When I run the app, it shows only 5 elements, cause the fifth throws an exception ("org.json.JSONException: No value for Title", and I know the Title is missing. I just want to know to solve this) and the rest of the array elements arent read.

Here is the code:

[image]

I've read in other questions that we can use "ourobject.has("whatwewant")" but my teacher says it has to be done other way. Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you use Retrofit?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exception? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: @Mohsen Just edited the original post

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Nop. It's just an experimental test, so we can learn how to parse JSon Strings

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Paste code in a code block instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sixth item in the JSON you are using does not have the `title` key.

Since you are not allowed to use "ourobject.has("whatwewant")".

Just replace your code that uses `speaker.getString()` with this instead:

```
 String name = speaker.optString("Name", "Name NA");
 String image= speaker.optString("Image", "Image NA");
```

The `opt` method (there are several `optString()`, optLong()`, optBoolean()`...) will return the set value if it is available or it will return what ever value you put as a "fallback"  if the key is not available.

Comment: And where do I put that  piece of code? In the catch on in the try?

Comment: @RodrigoSerra :: I have edited my answer to show you how to use the `optString()` method based on your code. Simply replace `getString(keyName)` with the `optString(keyName, fallbackValue)` equivalent.

Comment: oooooh okay okay. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @RodrigoSerra :: If this answer has helped you solve your issue, please consider accepting this answer as correct. That way the question will be closed and other developers will be informed.

Answer (score -1):

Since you can't use the `jsonObject.has("tag")`, you can also break up the try-catch block.

```
String name;
try {
    name = speaker.getString("name");
} catch (Exception e) {
    name = ""; // Occurs when it can't find the tag.
}
```

Repeat this for every field. Please be intentional using this outside of the classroom.